# How to remove element when that is unselected using checkbox in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few checkboxes with name. when i checked checkbox then i want to add that one in selected filter list that is working fine but now i want to remove it when i unselected checkbox. How can do that?

What i tried:-

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter-list li input').click(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).next('span').text();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.selected-filters ul').prepend('<li>' + thisVal + '<span class="remove-filter">X</span></li>');
    } else {}
  })
})
```

```css
.selected-filters {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.selected-filters h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: hindSemibold;
  color: #005173;
}

.selected-filters ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.selected-filters ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #f6fdff;
}

.selected-filters ul li a {
  color: #333;
}

.selected-filters ul li span.remove-filter {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-filters ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="selected-filters">
  <h5>Selected Filters</h5>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>


<ul class="filter-list">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andhra Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Arunachal Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Assam</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Bihar</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer will be appreciated:-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [**`:contains()`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector which select all elements that contain the ***specified text***:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.filter-list li input').click(function(){
    var thisVal = $(this).next('span').text();
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $('.selected-filters ul').prepend('<li>' + thisVal + '<span class="remove-filter">X</span></li>');
    }
    else{
      $('.selected-filters ul li:contains('+thisVal+')').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected-filters{ padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 8px; overflow: hidden;}
.selected-filters h5{ font-size: 14px; font-family: hindSemibold;  color: #005173;}
.selected-filters ul{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.selected-filters ul li{ list-style: none; float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 4px; font-size: 13px; padding: 1px 5px; background: #f6fdff;}
.selected-filters ul li a{ color: #333;}
.selected-filters ul li span.remove-filter{ font-size: 11px; padding-left: 5px; cursor: pointer;}
.selected-filters ul li a:hover{ text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-filters">
  <h5>Selected Filters</h5>
  <ul></ul>
</div>

<ul class="filter-list">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andhra Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Arunachal Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Assam</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Bihar</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to build an array of the checked boxes using the `:checked` selector and `map()`. Then you can replace all `li` within the `ul` based on the HTML in that array. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $checkboxes = $('.filter-list li input').on('click', function() {
    var html = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return '<li>' + $(this).next().text() + '<span class="remove-filter">X</span></li>';
    }).get();
    $('.selected-filters ul').html(html);
  })
})
```

```css
.selected-filters {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.selected-filters h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: hindSemibold;
  color: #005173;
}

.selected-filters ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.selected-filters ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #f6fdff;
}

.selected-filters ul li a {
  color: #333;
}

.selected-filters ul li span.remove-filter {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-filters ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-filters">
  <h5>Selected Filters</h5>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<ul class="filter-list">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andhra Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Arunachal Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Assam</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Bihar</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you are a bullet.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it like the below example.

You can make a custom attribute and add text of checkbox in custom attribute and via checking custom attribute's value in else condition you can remove it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter-list li input').click(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).next('span').text();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.selected-filters ul').prepend('<li data-val="'+thisVal+'">' + thisVal + '<span class="remove-filter">X</span></li>');
    } else {
        $('.selected-filters ul li[data-val="'+thisVal+'"]').remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.selected-filters {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.selected-filters h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: hindSemibold;
  color: #005173;
}

.selected-filters ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.selected-filters ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #f6fdff;
}

.selected-filters ul li a {
  color: #333;
}

.selected-filters ul li span.remove-filter {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-filters ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="selected-filters">
  <h5>Selected Filters</h5>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>


<ul class="filter-list">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Andhra Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Arunachal Pradesh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Assam</span></label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>Bihar</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! @Nirav Joshi